# Why cant i resize my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage

I have a dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu. My Ubuntu was lacking space and free some from the Windows partition. Now I want to expand the Linux system, but GParted does not let me do it. How to expand it?

[image]

[image]

I logged in with Windows and tried to resize with the "EaseUS Partition Master 13.5" tool. Same. I could not do it.

Comment: The *lock* symbol tells you which partitions are in use, thus cannot be expanded. It's easiest to boot a *live* system (eg. Ubuntu install media) so your hdd/ssd partitions are not in-use.

Answer (score 0):

Your partitions are locked because they are in use by a running system. You need to boot into a live environment and run GParted from there. You can do this with your Ubuntu install media.

Comment: That mean I could log in into Windows and repartition from there?

Comment: I logged in with Windows and tried to resize with the "EaseUS Partition Master 13.5" tool. Same. I could not do it.